# How to adjust brightness on Lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, brightness

I can't adjust my screen brightness. Indeed, I can't find this option in my system parameters. I am using Lubuntu 12.04.
Thank you for your time :)

Comment: What graphics and driver are you using? Please add the output of `lspci -v`.

Comment: SOLVED ! I installed xbacklight and it works perfectly

Comment: If you solved the problem, add it as your own answer (with a short method of how you did it) below and mark it as answered so the question can be closed.

Comment: here is oneliner `sudo apt-get install -y xbacklight && xbacklight -set 30`

Comment: Why is there always someone asking some complicated and often irrelevant question? Though this one is nice, at least he says how to obtain the answer. Often it's more like "What is your ekltcnelcti?"

Answer (score 5):

This one worked for me, hope it might help  someone.
Brightness is the default tool to control your screen brightness.
**How to Launch**
To launch Brightness from the menu Preferences ‣ LXQt settings ‣ Brightness. Another way is to press the Brightness icon on LXQt Configuration Center or run below command on terminal.

```
lxqt-config-brightness
```

However **lxqt-config** was not installed in my case already. So I did install it first with below command and then just executed above command to launch brightness tool.

```
sudo apt install lxqt-config
```

[image]

More details you can refer here
https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/3/3.2/3.2.3/brightness.html

Answer (score 2):

You can solve your problem by using [xbacklight](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man1/xbacklight.1.html) which uses the RandR extension.
Install it using:

```bsh
sudo apt-get install -y xbacklight
```

Use it:

```bsh
xbacklight -set 45
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not a pro, I am only posting what worked for me

Go to taskbar, right click on the battery icon, there's option for brightness.

or

```
sudo apt-get install brightness-controller
```

but the brightness goes back to full if charger is plugged in/out or if you reboot your machine, that means you have to do it again and again.

Answer (score 1):

Installing `xbacklight` did not do the trick for me.

I then used the already available `xrandr` utility as follows:

1. Find the connected monitor name.

```
$ xrandr | grep " connected" | cut -f1 -d " "
HDMI-0
```

2. Change the brightness level for the connected monitor.

`$ xrandr --output HDMI-0 --brightness 0.75`

Linux distro: Pop!_OS 20.04 LTS

Comment: This worked for me as well!

Answer (score 0):

I found the Indicator Brightness quite useful.

https://launchpad.net/~indicator-brightness/+archive/ppa

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look here:

[StackOverview](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/322814/xf86monbrightnessup-xf86monbrightnessdown-special-keys-not-working#_=_)

```
bl_device=/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
echo $(($(cat $bl_device)+1)) | sudo tee $bl_device # brightness up

bl_device=/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness 
echo $(($(cat $bl_device)-1)) | sudo tee $bl_device # brightness down

bl_device=/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
echo 5 | sudo tee $bl_device # given value

cat /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness # get value
```

Very smart and simple solution at that page.

Comment: Thanks @xerostomus, this solution worked for me. Just one correction in my case it is intel_backlight instead acpi_video0. So for others before executing above command just check whats there inside backlight folder using ```ls /sys/class/backlight/ ```

Comment: That is for Arch Linux

Answer (score 0):

In the terminal, you can type:
xgamma -gamma 0.6

The default value is 1.
Anything higher than 1, for example 1.2, makes the screen brighter.

The fact that it's a command-line control means you can make it persistent (when you reboot this command is run automatically).